# Can't Compare EditText Value with SharedPreference Value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

When I enter a value in the EditText, i can't to compare it with a Value in My SharedPreference .

This is my EditText Preference

```
<EditTextPreference

        android:defaultValue="1234"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:key="userid"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:summary="To Access App setting set a PIN"
        android:title="Set PIN" />
```

And This is My Methode code:

```
private void GoToSettings(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
    String userpin = prefs.getString("userid", "");
    String userpin1 = txtpin.getText().toString();
    if(userpin.equals(userpin1)){
                        /*Intent intent = new Intent(FingerprintScannerActivity.this, PreferencesActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);*/
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Good",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Error PIN",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: Solved : I forget to load PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences_xml, false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
> String userpin = prefs.getString("userid", "");
> ```

change it to : `String userpin = prefs.getString("userid", null);`
its more efficient to return null instead of empty string and then you can use:

```
if((userpin == null) ? (userpin1 == null) : userpin.equalsIgnoreCase(userpin1))
```

Comment: Error PIN Appear Again :s :s

Comment: @YsenEycen it doesnt mean that the  comparison was worng.
print here the value of the 'userid' value in the sharedPref 
`Log.d(TAG, userpin + " " userpin1);`

Comment: Code work only when i open the setting activity and i set the value in the editText , otherwise without opening the setting activity code dosn't work

Comment: Solved : I forget to load PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences_xml, false);

Answer (score 0):

Whenever comparing `Strings` use the following approach

`string1.equals(string2)`

Don't use '==' operator for strings 
See this for more detailed answer [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Comment: The same problem , When I click the button message appears in the instruction else